# How to block all connections (except windows update) until Windows 10 is fully updated?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, operating-systems

I want to block all connections (except windows update) until Windows 10 is fully updated. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This will be impossible without running the update in a Virtual Machine, or another configurable firewall outside Windows during update. There is no way I can see to firewall your boot process otherwise.

This is partially why most businesses have firewalls setup and ruled in routers, and if your router is Linux underneath, and can be accessed with write capability you can modify the etc/hosts file to exclude all non-microsoft IPs, but the discovery and workability of that depends on hardware outside the scope of your question, and my immediate knowledge. Should be on google though.

If you wish to run in a VM, load a Live Linux CD, and a reasonably fast memory stick with which to store host. Make sure you have swap enabled, then use any Firewall from the internet to 'ask all connections'. Load VirtualBox and set target to your Windows HDD, and Windows should (unhappily/slowly, due to all the drivers it will try and fail to load for your usual hardware - your VM has replaced all that) load your OS and allow you to run Windows Update without hassle. You can safely assume that all software will not be able to breach your firewall on Linux